# Scheduling Algorithm for a multi-server queue problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, operations-research

I have 4 servers, n customers and m reports. At any time, a customer may request one of m reports. There are only 4 servers which are capable of generating reports. Each server can only process one report at a time. Over time I can record the average generation time for each customer which is independent of the server. I assume that the arrival is Poisson Process.

I would like to come up with the optimal schedule minimizing the average queue size. In other words, if I currently have say 10 customers in the system requesting 10 different report, how do I pick the order of serving these customers (other than first come, first serve)

I'm familiar with some Stochastic Processes and Probability Methods. However, I'm struggling with:

1. How do I determine the distribution if it depends on each report?
2. If I don't assume Poisson arrival, how do I determine the distribution?
3. What kind of algorithms would be the best to minimize the average time?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to come up with the optimal schedule minimizing the average queue size. In other words, if I currently have say 10 customers in the system requesting 10 different report, how do I pick the order of serving these customers (other than first come, first serve)

**You can't!**

The order in which jobs get processed is controlled by the service discipline. The [service discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_scheduler) only determines which job gets processed next. It does not affect the rates of completion.

If you want to optimize the average queue size you'll need to address two rates. For a single queue, i.e. no routing between queues, you can think of the rates in terms of a [Lindley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindley_equation)-type equation:

$$\Delta \text{Length}_t := \max \left( 0,\text{Arrivals}_t - \text{Served}_t - \text{Reneged}_t \right)$$

If you cannot control any of these variables then you cannot control how the length of the queue changes. (Note: Reneging is when the job is not served before leaving the queue. See [Bocquet 2005](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA444342.pdf) for further discussion).

> How do I determine the distribution if it depends on each report?
> If I don't assume Poisson arrival, how do I determine the distribution?

You'll need to fit distribution models to the data to decide which probability distribution best matches reality.